# (compiling CRdroid) REPO SYNC EROR: "fatal: remove-project element specifies non-existent project: CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Mms"

Tags: android, ubuntu, github

I am fairly new to android roms, I have mastered the art of installing them so I want to get into building them...
I use CRDroid on my 2012 nexus 7 and my nexus 5X and really enjoy the overall performance and features so I decided to attempt to compile it myself using this guide:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-build-crdroid-rom-from-source.2884765/

**the problem I ran into was syncing the repository:**
"https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-11.0"
when I typed `repo sync` I get the response:

```
... A new version of repo (2.29) is available.
... You should upgrade soon:
    cp /home/wsl/android/crdroid/.repo/repo/repo /home/wsl/bin/repo

fatal: remove-project element specifies non-existent project: CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Mms
```

NB: I am not worried about the new version of repo...

looking at a few posts with peole who have a similar issue to me, the `.repo/local_manifests/` folder containing `roomservice.xml` can have somthing to do with the features so I have attached the contense of the afformentioned xml file below... please note there is no other files in the `.repo/local_manifests` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <project name="TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_oneplus" path="vendor/oneplus" remote="github" />
  <project name="TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_oppo" path="vendor/oppo" remote="github" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_device_oneplus_bacon" path="device/oneplus/bacon" remote="github" revision=>  <project name="cristianomatos/android_device_oppo_msm8974-common" path="device/oppo/msm8974-common" remote="githu>  <project name="CyanogenMod/android_device_oppo_common" path="device/oppo/common" remote="github" />
  <project name="CyanogenMod/android_kernel_oneplus_msm8974" path="kernel/oneplus/msm8974" remote="github" />
  <project name="CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_display-caf-new" path="hardware/qcom/display-caf-new" remote="gi>  <project name="CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_media-caf-new" path="hardware/qcom/media-caf-new" remote="github>  <project name="CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_opt_connectivity" path="frameworks/opt/connectivity" remote="github>  <project name="CyanogenMod/android_device_qcom_common" path="device/qcom/common" remote="github" />
  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_build" />
  <project path="build" name="cristianomatos/android_build" groups="pdk" >
    <copyfile src="core/root.mk" dest="Makefile" />
  </project>
  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cm" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_vendor_cm" path="vendor/cm" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" />
  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_CMAccount" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_apps_CMAccount" path="packages/apps/CMAccount" remote="github" rev>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_DSPManager" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_apps_DSPManager" path="packages/apps/DSPManager" remote="github" r>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Dialer" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_apps_Dialer" path="packages/apps/Dialer" remote="github" revision=>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_providers_DownloadProvider" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_providers_DownloadProvider" path="packages/providers/DownloadProvi>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_InCallUI" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_apps_InCallUI" path="packages/apps/InCallUI" remote="github" revis>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_services_Telephony" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_services_Telephony" path="packages/services/Telephony" remote="git>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Mms" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_apps_Mms" path="packages/apps/Mms" remote="github" revision="cm-11>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_providers_MediaProvider" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_providers_MediaProvider" path="packages/providers/MediaProvider" r>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_system_media" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_system_media" path="system/media" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" />
  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_frameworks_base" path="frameworks/base" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" >  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings" />
  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_apps_Settings" path="packages/apps/Settings" remote="github" revis>  <project name="cristianomatos/android_packages_apps_ScreenRecorder" path="packages/apps/ScreenRecorder" remote="g>  <project name="cristianomatos/android_frameworks_opt_cards" path="frameworks/opt/cards" remote="github" revision=>  <remove-project name="CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_CMUpdater" />
</manifest>
```

I was expecting for the repository to sync and have to wait while the code is downloading.
I have not attempted any fixes bcause I am currently unsure how to tackle the problem.Thank you so much in advance!

Luca aka Phsyphix
PS: I am using UBUNTU WSL2 on windows 11 however I do not believe this is contributing to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: PROBLEM SOLVED! BY COMMENTING OUT THE CONFLICTING LINES IN ROOMSERVICE.XML!!!
[commented out code (revert back to crdroid mms...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKsOp.png)